# Java MySQL deployment error (UnsupportedOperationException)

Tags: java, sql, tomcat, netbeans, wicket

I am working on a Wicket project and having a problem. Here is my piece of code:

```
private static String select_fkey = "SELECT fullname FROM PROFILE"; 
private static String select_table = "SELECT * FROM MESSAGE ORDER BY id DESC"; 



try{

        String query = select_table;
        Statement statement = this.connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);

        while(result.next()){

            this.list.add(getMessage(result));
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e){

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(e.getMessage());
    }

private Message getMessage(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException{

        Statement sender_statement = this.connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet sender_result = sender_statement.executeQuery(select_fkey + " WHERE (id = " + rs.getInt("sender_id") + ")");

        return new Message(rs.getInt("id"), 
                           rs.getString("content"),  
                           rs.getInt("sender_id"), 
                           rs.getInt("receiver_id"),
                           rs.getString("datetime"),
                           sender_result.getString("fullname"));
    }
```

The table `MESSAGE` has these 5 fields and I wanted to define a `Message` object that also stores the name of the person sends it.

The problem is, I actually don't know how to get information from a related table so I tried this way but it catches the `UnsupportedOperationException` (according to Apache Tomcat server log) and gives a deployment error. Is there any proper way to do this operation? Or, what am I doing wrong?

By the way, it clearly runs with this function instead of the one above:

```
private Message getMessage(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException{

            return new Message(rs.getInt("id"), 
                               rs.getString("content"),  
                               rs.getInt("sender_id"), 
                               rs.getInt("receiver_id"),
                               rs.getString("datetime"));
        }
```

Error messages:

```
nbproject/build-impl.xml:1027: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
```

build-impl.xml:1027 says:

```
<nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="true" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
```

Comment: Paste a relevant fragment of the log, don't assume things about it and show it (or paste it into pastebin, hiding private data).

Comment: This type of error appears when deploying the application. Maybe are you missing any relevant library? Please show the tomcat logs.